# Is there a standard way to notate random-note stabs in a certain rhythm?

Tags: notation, rhythm, improvisation, pitch

e.g. What the percussionist plays on [the Cardiacs's Seaside album version of "Hope Day" at 4:15](https://youtu.be/8sI0rPt53ng&t=4m15s)

Comment: What makes you think this is random ;) ?

Comment: I understand your question to mean that the rhythm would be notated precisely, but within that either the accented moments or the pitches used would be random. Please clarify.

Comment: You mean like the improvisation mode in LilyPond? http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/note-heads#improvisation

Comment: Yes! That’s what I mean (yo’ and Aaron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Random pitches

Elaine Gould's *Behind Bars* (Faber Music, 2011) addresses this situation in the section "Options to show approximate pitch / On the stave / Stems without noteheads" (page 640).

> The end of the stem where the notehead would normally be placed indicates the approximate position of a pitch.... Note that if stems are placed in a uniform position this may encourage a monotone delivery.... The absence of noteheads may also be used to represent *ad libitum* pitch choices — a performance note can specify *free pitch*....

Since the intention here is for entirely unspecified pitches, I recommend placing headless rhythmic notation above the staff along with the instruction "pitches ad lib." By placing the rhythm above a full staff, it makes clear that pitches are intended, but eliminates any sense of approximate pitch or monotone execution. Using a smaller font will also help make clear the exceptional nature of the notation.

[image: Example of headless rhythm notation]

#### Random pitched percussion

Since there's a specific instrument involved — a pitched percussion instrument — the same advice can be taken, but placed on a single-line staff, which is often used for percussion parts. In this case, the instrument would be specified along with the "pitches ad lib." instruction.

Answer (score 4):

The rhythm in the part of the song you link doesn't seem random at all. It's moderately complex, but for sure can be perfectly notated and read.

However, to try to answer the question, you can write **ad libitum** which means "as desired" to indicate you give the performer freedom in how to perform some section of music. This term however can be interpreted in many ways, so you may want to add some explanation or suggestion of what you mean exactly. For example *tempo ad libitum* would mean one can play at any tempo they like, while *solo ad libitum* means to improvise a solo. At this stage you can get as creative as you like, you can add your own graphic marks to inspire the performer, but be aware they may play something very different from what you thought about!

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_libitum

Comment: Sorry :/… https://youtu.be/UWdJ0jbHKms?t=82

Comment: @Tom good one! :D